# jQuery Circle Progressbar starting 0 value is incorrectly showing

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsbin.com/nadozi/edit?html,js,output

Here is my JSBin.

I'm trying to initialize the circle with `value = 0`, but it shows a Dot as starting point. Only happens when `lineCap` is **round**. How can I hide it and start as blank grayed circle when starting fresh circle?

This is the library I'm trying to use:
https://github.com/kottenator/jquery-circle-progress

Comment: does that answer your question??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was identified and acknowledged here - [GitHub - Issue #108](https://github.com/kottenator/jquery-circle-progress/issues/108)

The workaround to bypass drawing when value is 0 also worked:

```
drawArc: function(v) {
  // introduced this value check so that arc is rendered only when value is > 0
  if (this.getValue() > 0) {
    var ctx = this.ctx,
        r = this.radius,
        t = this.getThickness(),
        a = this.startAngle;

    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();

    if (!this.reverse) {
      ctx.arc(r, r, r - t / 2, a, a + Math.PI * 2 * v);
    } else {
      ctx.arc(r, r, r - t / 2, a - Math.PI * 2 * v, a);
    }

    ctx.lineWidth = t;
    ctx.lineCap = this.lineCap;
    ctx.strokeStyle = this.arcFill;
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.restore();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? I used the more examples link to this page       http://kottenator.github.io/jquery-circle-progress/

```
$('.circle').circleProgress({
value: 1.0,
fill: { color: '#ffa500' }
}).on('circle-animation-progress', function(event, progress) {
$(this).find('strong').html(parseInt(100 * progress) + '<i>%</i>');
});
```